# Share a heroku basic postgres DB between 2 heroku apps

Tags: postgresql, heroku

Having googled it (and looked on the heroku site) - i just can't find a set for instructions for setting a new rails app's database connection to be to a basic db created for a different (earlier) app. I know there's something to do with swapping the "color" of the databases available - but i have no idea how... and links or any simple instructions massively appreciated.

ps - i gave seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981508/share-database-between-2-apps-in-heroku) question, but it is a couple of years old, and it seems things have moved on at heroku since then.

Answer (score 4):

Go into the directory you are pushing to Heroku and type the following:

```
heroku config:set DATABASE_URL=`heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a other-app`
```

Where "other-app" is the database from the app you created earlier. For example:

```
heroku config:set DATABASE_URL=`heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a running-tree-4822`
```

More detailed instructions are on Heroku's web site:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#sharing-heroku-postgres-between-applications

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981508/share-database-between-2-apps-in-heroku) you reference is still relevant. There's also a blog post with more details [here](http://neilmiddleton.com/sharing-databases-between-heroku-applications/).

Comment: Blog post link is dead