# How to change database_url on heroku?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I am trying to share a database between two apps on `Heroku` according to [Share database between 2 apps in Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981508/share-database-between-2-apps-in-heroku) but setting up database_url on the second app gives an error:

```
$ heroku config:add DATABASE_URL=postgres://...
Setting config vars and restarting pacific-headland-1960... failed  
 !    Cannot destroy last attachment to billing app for resource loving-subtly-5807
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`DATABASE_URL` is what's currently storing your second app's connection to its provisioned DB, which Heroku is kindly preventing you from deleting because there are no other references to it.

First, remove the second application's DB. **Anything in it will be destroyed.**

```sh
heroku addons:destroy heroku-postgresql:<your DB tier> --app <your second app>
```

If these are new apps, your DB tier is probably `hobby-dev`, but you can check for it by running `heroku addons --app <your second app>`.

Then, you'll be able to set `DATABASE_URL` on the second app.

If you want to have the second app connected to both DBs, you'll need to store the first app's DB URL in a different environment variable and update your second app's code to use it.

---

Unrelated to your question, you've just pasted your DB credentials into a public space. You should roll them with `heroku pg:credentials --reset --app <your first application>`.

Docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql

Comment: Woow I browsed back to this question and saw what I copypasted - wow it is too early for me to post on the internet ;)

Comment: I feel ya :-D Definitely still roll the creds since there's an [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30611801/revisions)

Comment: Kristjan if you dont mind a followup, I try to connect to the database with 'heroku pg:psql' but it says: 'Your app has no databases.'. According to documentation this command should fall on DATABASE_URL. Would you have any idea why I cant connect?

Comment: I would've guessed Heroku just uses the configured `DATABASE_URL` for that too, but maybe the CLI is looking at your addons, which now app 2 doesn't have. You should still be able to run `pg:psql` on app 1, where the database addon is present.

Answer (score 0):

From [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/managing-add-ons)

> Previously to add an add-on you could use the command `addons:add`. That command is now deprecated in favor of the `create` command.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem.

1. You need to detach any db addon from the application you want to change DATABASE_URL in.
2. Run `heroku config:remove DATABASE_URL`
3. Run `heroku config:add DATABASE_URL="my_fancy_db_connection"`

The last step really tripped me up, but I was trying without the quotes. Adding those in made it work.