# Deploying Ruby on Rails app to Heroku while using Action Cable (Puma port listening)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, puma, actioncable

I have got Action Cable working in a local host environment and in this situation I start the Puma server using a simple file containing

```
# /bin/bash
bundle exec puma -p 28080 cable/config.ru
```

Once this happens the puma server starts and is listening to this 28080 port and the port the local server is running on.  Through hunting online I couldn't find a place that would tell me a way to emulate this on heroku or a way to have my server always start on the same port (though I don't know if that would give me the desired result either)

I have a javascript file set up to create a consumer related to that port.

```
//= require cable
//= require_self
//= require_tree .


this.App = {};

App.cable = Cable.createConsumer('ws://127.0.0.1:28080');
```

I imagine I'll need to change the 127.0.0.1 part as well for the deploy to heroku to work as well but I'm not certain.  I attempted to cut off the 28080 part and replace it with ENV['PORT'] but it said it was an unknown variable even though I have a puma.rb file set up which has its port set as

```
... (only part of the file)
rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'
...
```

So it seemed to me that ENV['PORT'] was being defined as when I check the heroku logs the puma server will be

```
2015-07-26T06:50:25.278030+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 48875 -e production`
2015-07-26T06:50:30.760680+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2015-07-26T06:50:30.760714+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:48875
2015-07-26T06:50:30.760716+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-07-26T06:50:30.760718+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-07-26T06:50:31.578843+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma 2.12.2 starting...
2015-07-26T06:50:31.578851+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
2015-07-26T06:50:31.578859+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2015-07-26T06:50:31.578861+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:48875
```

I apologize if anything is unclear and would be happy to provide any more information if I left anything out.

EDIT

Here is the updated code in /app/assets/javascripts/channels/index.js.erb

```
//= require cable
//= require_self
//= require_tree .

this.App = {};

App.cable = Cable.createConsumer('<%= ENV["CABLE_SERVER"] %>');
```

where ENV["CABLE_SERVER"] points to `ws://the-action-cable-server.herokuapp.com`.  This variable is stored in the rails server env variables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Issue

There are some limits to the Heroku [router](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing%20router): it will only listen to ports 80 and 443. In other words, you can't open a fixed port on any Heroku application. In the ActionCable server case, there is no way to open a fixed port and get the websocket traffic routed to it. So either Heroku allows such things (which I doubt) or we use a workaround.

### Workaround

As of version 0.0.3 of actioncable, here is the workaround I used.

The idea is to have not one Heroku application but two: one for the main rails server and one for the ActionCable server. Both would run on port 80 (or 443).

To run two different servers from one codebase is simply a matter of having two Procfiles: one for rails and one for action cable. There is a [buildpack](https://github.com/cantino/heroku-selectable-procfile) to handle this. To use it, you also need the [multi buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi.git).

Let's say you have your two Heroku applications called `rails` and `actioncable`.

Create a `.buildpacks` file in the root of your project with this:

```
https://github.com/cantino/heroku-selectable-procfile
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby
```

On `rails` and `actioncable`, create an env var `BUILDPACK_URL` with `https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi.git`

Now for the Procfiles, I choose to keep `Procfile` for running everything locally with foreman and create two custom ones: `Procfile.rails` and `Procfile.actioncable`.

In `Procfile.rails`, you describe all the needed dynos **except** the action cable server, eg.:

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma/config.rb
clockwork: bundle exec clockwork lib/clockwork.rb
worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

In `Procfile.actioncable`, you describe **only** the action cable server:

```
web: bundle exec puma -p $PORT cable/config.ru
```

Note that we are using a `web` dyno which will mount the action cable server on port 80 (or 443).

**CAUTION** You need to move the puma config file `config/puma.rb` to a custom location. I choose `config/puma/config.rb`. `config/puma.rb` is the default location when you start puma without any specific config file, which is what we have in `Procfile.actioncable`. This can lead to unexpected behaviors (see the comments below).

Now, on `rails`, create an env var `PROCFILE_PATH` with `Procfile.rails` and on `actioncable`, create an env var `PROCFILE_PATH` with `Procfile.actioncable`.

Speaking of env vars, the `actioncable` needs all the env vars from `rails` that are necessary to start the actioncable server like the DATABASE_URL or any credentials.

Now the crucial step: how do we connect `rails` and `actioncable` together? This is simply done by using the **same** Redis instance. `rails` will put messages on Redis and `actioncable` will listen to them and act accordingly. That's why both have to target the **same** Redis instance. If you using Heroku Redis, you just need to set `REDIS_URL` with the same value on `rails` **and** `actioncable`. Here is the config file for the cable server `cable.yml`:

```
production: &production
  :url: <%= ENV["REDIS_URL"] %>
  :timeout: 1
development: &development
  :url: <%= ENV["REDIS_URL"] %>
  :timeout: 1
  :inline: true
test: *development
```

The final step is changing the javascript file so that we can control where is the Action Cable server. We can do this by using an env var.

Change the `.js` suffix into `.js.erb` if necessary.

```
//= require cable
//= require_self
//= require_tree .


this.App = {};

App.cable = Cable.createConsumer('<%= ENV["CABLE_SERVER"] %>');
```

This `CABLE_SERVER` variable can now point to `ws://127.0.0.1:28080` locally and on `rails`, the value will be the url of `actioncable`.

Now you're ready to deploy the code on `rails` and `actioncable`.

### Caveats/Drawbacks

- on `actioncable`, if you have any client authentication, you can't use `cookies` like in the [examples](https://github.com/rails/actioncable-examples/blob/master/app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb#L12). You have now two Heroku apps and they can't share a cookie. I guess you can still [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10403338/2159281) this using a cookie for multiple subdomains.
- you have now two deploy targets to maintain.
- you have multiple Procfiles to maintain.
- hopefully, with time, there will be an easier workaround :)

### Alternatives

- We can have the same server handling the normal web traffic *and* the websocket traffic using a simple middleware. [Here](http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/deploying-action-cable-to-heroku/) is how.
- As of rails 5 beta2, the action cable server can now also be [side-mounted](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actioncable#in-app) along with your main rails app. Having two different servers can still make sense: you can scale them individually.

hth

Comment: Also when the actioncable starts up it prints in the logs 


`2015-07-31T23:21:18.708169+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process    with command bundle exec puma -p 28389 cable/config.ru`

I don't know if that means I need to change the ws url to include a port designation?  For the cable_server variable I just took the URL of the heroku app for the action cable server and changed http to ws and I  guess that's not all there is to it.  thanks

Comment: I also see that you mention that I need the actioncable server to have the rails database_url but if I try to change the one that heroku generated for me (I'm using the heroku-postgresql addon) it tells me that it can't allow that update and that value can't be overwritten.  Is that a problem?

Comment: Also this is an aside but is there any way to check that I have my redis connections set up properly at least?  I just added  
    `production:`
      `:url: ENV["REDIS_URL"]`
      `:host: ec2-54-83-33-255.compute-1.amazonaws.com`
      `:port: 13379`
      `:timeout: 1`

to `config/redis/cable.yml`.  Just realized there's no codeblocks in comments.  Breaks in the code signify new lines.

Comment: Haven't been able to put too much time into getting this working yet but I am running into an error. I don't know if I am using the correct URL or not as the cable_server variable. `WebSocket connection to 'ws://URLstart-actioncable.herokuapp.com/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500`. To set up the streams I create a stream for every user combination possible (I couldn't get namespaces working and had little time) so I don't think user authentication is the issue here. This error is in the console. It repeats every ~fifteen seconds

Comment: It seems that your cable server is throwing some errors. You should have something in the logs `heroku logs -a actioncable`.
I added the `cable.yml` configuration in my answer. As you can see, you need to have `ENV["REDIS_URL"]` enclosed with `<%= %>`. That could explain why your action cable server is throwing errors.
As for the port on actioncable. Don't worry, it's fine. Heroku assigns a random port to your dyno. The router will receive the request on 80/442 and reroute it correctly to your dyno.

Comment: I have changed the cable.yml file to match your posting and I'm still getting the same websocket error.  If I have the CABLE_SERVER value to be an http://some_url.herokuapp.com then it tells me it must be a ws or wss but if I have that it gives me the same handshake error.  I tried also adding :80 to the end just in case and it didn't work.  http://imgur.com/a/10FMb  The top image is the action cable heroku log, the middle image is the bottom half of the rails heroku logs and the bottom image is the top half of the rails heroku logs (omitted pictures loading).

Comment: I just want to add that my redis.heroku link shows there being two connections to it.  And earlier you mentioned that they should have the same DATABASE_URL but when I try to change it it tells me that isn't allowed.  So there is no need to specify the redis port though?  I really don't get why this isn't working, I tested on local host again for my sanity and it was fine.   Should the cable_server variable really just be ws://fakest-actioncable.herokuapp.com ??  Or with http?  Though that broke all the JS on my page even.

Comment: Can you post in your question your js code with the `App.cable = Cable.createConsumer` call. The weird thing in your action cable log is that the status should be 101 and in your case it's 200. Ah yes, the `DATABASE_URL` issue, check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30611801/how-to-change-database-url-on-heroku.

Comment: Updated original question and can confirm now that the actioncable server is connected to the correct DB but still getting the same error.

Comment: Here is what you should have in your cable log: http://i.imgur.com/waw127Z.png. That's an example of a subscription on a channel.

I'd try to hunt down the handshake error (status 500) in the logs of actioncable

Comment: So does the js code I added to the original question look correct at least?  I might just try a different provider than heroku cause I don't know what the issue is here really.  It all works on localhost..

Comment: Yep your js code looks good. You can even search in the compiled js file (usually application.js). You should be able to find something like `App.cable = Cable.createConsumer('ws://the-action-cable-server.herokuapp.com');`

Comment: Is there any special configuration of the Puma servers required or something?  Because my heroku logs never show anything like what yours appear like.   Have you tried this with the latest version of actioncable as well?  I'm using the newest version from github.  I did find that code in the compiled js.

Comment: Do you happen to have the config file for puma in `config/puma.rb` ?

Comment: I do have the config file for the `rails` dyno puma configuration has shown on heorku ( https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#config ) located at `config/puma.rb` .  My `Procfile.rails` reflects that though so I thought it should be fine.  `web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb` along with the two other lines untouched that you suggested.

Comment: I remember having a weird situation where the `actioncable` server would pickup settings from the `config/puma.rb` file, which is wrong. Try to move the `config/puma.rb` to a new location, like `config/puma/config.rb` and reflect this change in `Procfile.rails` and `Procfile`.

Comment: I will never EVER deviate from instructions again just since I assume "oh that must not be important I understand what is happening there and I already have it set up this way" in my life.  That totally fixed it!  It works now.

Comment: After some digging, `config/puma.rb` is the default location for the config file: https://github.com/puma/puma#configuration-file. I should have RTFM. I'll update my answer to make this point more explicit. Glad to hear is working. So everything's is good? The websocket connection is opened? You see those 101 statuses?

Comment: Actually I guess it's really dumb in my exuberance that I didn't check the heroku logs.  Nothing shows up in the browser console (no errors) and the chat works (in real time, there's no ajax set up for that either) so that just meant to me the websocket connection has to be working so I was like "cool" and stopped.  I will examine it more tomorrow/soon as I still need to hook up an image hosting service before I can really 'show it off' as a project I made.

Comment: Using chrome, you can open the dev tools and check in the "Network" tab that you have a connection to your actioncable server. You'll see that the status is 101 and if you click on the row, you can actually see the messages going on through the websocket. Even if you don't do anything, you should see a message each 3secs. That's a heartbeat message used by actioncable to actually check that the websocket connection is not in a stale state.