# Trying to connect my herokuApp to an outside postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm trying to connect my Heroku App to an outside PostgreSQL. But I keep getting a connection refused error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (could not connect to server: Connection refused
2018-08-30T12:44:46.868880+00:00 app[web.1]: Is the server running on       host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
2018-08-30T12:44:46.868882+00:00 app[web.1]: TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

In my Heroku Admin I've set my DATABASE_URL to point to my PostgreSQL (No password)

[image]
    DATABASE_URL postgres://postgres:@localhost:5432/postgres

My database.yml looks like this

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

production:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

When I enter the command Heroku config I can definitely see my DATABASE_URL. What is the issue here?

Comment: Why not use herokus Postgres dB? You can export your local the free hosted.

Comment: We are experimenting the features of Heroku. The client might have their database separated

Comment: By an an outside PostgreSQL you mean localhost?

Comment: yes. Outside of Heroku

Comment: I think if you can change the heroku config `heroku config:set DATABASE_URL=postgres://user_name:password@host:port/database_name`. Make sure you're not behind firewall.

Comment: I already set it via the Heroku admin

Comment: You can remove the line `url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>` from `database.yml`. Rails merges `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` with the values from  `database.yml` anyways. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database

Comment: Also have you tried connecting to your postgres server in any other way to eliminate possible issues such as an IP whitelist? You can also try detaching the postgres addon on heroku. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35061914/how-to-change-database-url-for-a-heroku-application

Comment: I've already detached all Postgres addon on Heroku as well and still I'm getting a connection refused error. If I ran my Ruby and Rails on development environment and connect to Postgres it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

> DATABASE_URL postgres://postgres:@localhost:5432/postgres

That is setting the `DATABASE_URL` config var that is used in your app to use a database on `localhost` which will resolve to the machine the app is running on, hence the error.

What you probably want to do is change 'localhost' to be the IP address of where the Postgres instance is running along with credentials required to auth.

Comment: Already tried to replace localhost with my ip address and public address but still refuse to connect. Both heroku and postgres instance are in the same machine

Comment: ah ok, so you're running postgres locally and trying to connect your Heroku app (running on Heroku - which runs on Amazon) to your local database? This points towards a networking config issue.