# heroku - Item could not be updated:

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to add / modify Config Var, when I try to save the change I get a message:

> Item could not be updated:
>
> Unknown Error. Please contact support.

Any ideas on what may be wrong?

Comment: How are you "trying to save the change"? What's the name of the config var you're trying to set? Have you contacted support as suggested?

Comment: Any change is throwing error, for example, I'm trying to add MYAR with MYVAL value.

Comment: I am running the "free" heroku, I don't see any way to contact support, there is no email, the "Create ticket" brings me to a list of common questions, but still no way to create a ticket.

Comment: Again, _how_ are you trying to "save the change"? Are you doing it in the web panel? Via `heroku config:set`? What if you try to _read_ a variable, e.g. via `heroku config MYVAR`? It's unlikely that we're going to be able to help without more information.

Comment: I go to the dashboard and settings for my app: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/{myapp}/settings and do the "Releval config vars" and then I try to add or modify.

Comment: It could be an authentication issue. Try deleting all of your cookies etc. for Heroku, logging in again, and trying to set the config var.

Comment: I have logged out, cleared cookies, even tried in an "Incognito" mode and still, I'm getting the error.

Comment: Can you try destroying the app and recreating it? We're really just guessing at this point. Heroku support is likely in the best position to help you.

Comment: Chris, thanks for the attempts, must have been something wrong with the environment at work, when I have tried to update the variable on my phone, it went without any problems. Appreciate your help and time. Regards.

Comment: B0rG Had the same problem )))

Comment: Is your variable **DATABASE_URL**? If so, detach database first, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35061914/how-to-change-database-url-for-a-heroku-application).

Answer (score 3):

The below command solved my issue. Hope it works for others too.

**Using Heroku CLI:**

```
heroku config:set DB_PASSWORD=secret -a [heroku-app-name]
```

**Bonus Points:**

If Heroku CLI is not installed, you could use NPM to install it easily in [windows] system.

```
npm install -g heroku

heroku login
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to update in incognito mode or in different browser. It worked for me.