# Will a Heroku database exist after it's app is deleted - and can I transfer it to another app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have a Heroku app that is running on the `Cedar-10` stack which will soon be deprecated. I am following the [Migrating to the Celadon Cedar-14 Stack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-14-migration) guide and have created an instance of my app on the new stack. However, this has also created another (empty) `PostgreSQL` database automatically.

- Can I upgrade to the new stack but continue to use the existing database?
- When I delete app on the old stack, will it delete the database that is associated with it automatically?

I see that the database URL is set in the environment variable `$DATABASE_URL` - does that mean I can somehow update that and "link" the old database to the new app?

When searching for information on this I've come across heroku's `pg:copy` and `pg:transfer` directives, but it seems strange to duplicate the database when it is working fine, and has a paid "upgrade" and backups already associated with it.

Comment: Sounds like you created a staging instance. If you delete that instance and the empty db is still there, just delete it in the dashboard. Upgrading your production app is a completely separate process. Run the given commands and push your code. The new stack will be installed and talking to your production db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The problem with the configuration variable approach

While it is possible to [share a database between two applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981508/share-database-between-2-apps-in-heroku) in Heroku by copying the `DATABASE_URL` configuration variable of the first application to the second, only the first application will have a *primary connection* (add-on) to the database.

If you remove the first application, your database will disappear from the [postgres dashboard](https://postgres.heroku.com/databases) in Heroku. Although it seems the second application will still be able to use the database. *(Tested on 2015-10-25.)*

It is also worth noting that:

> Heroku do reserve the right to change database URLs as required. If this occurs, it will cause your secondary connections to fail, and you'll need to update the URLs accordingly.

What this means is that if Heroku decide to change the URL for your database, your new application will fail, and since the database is now gone from your dashboard, you will not be able to retrieve the new URL without approaching Heroku. (If at all.)

This implies that there is a more intrinsic connection between an application and its database than merely the `DATABASE_URL`, and it might not be the best idea to use this as a mechanism for transfer.

---

## An alternative approach using PGBackups

Heroku [official documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export) recommends using the free [PGBackups](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups) add-on (which, honestly, you should always be running anyway) to transfer data between Postgres instances. The tool uses the native `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` tools.

Particularly, you can use the [PG copy](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases#upgrade-with-pg-copy-default) feature, described below:

> PG copy uses the native PostgreSQL backup and restore utilities. Instead of writing the backup to a disk however, it streams it over the wire directly to the restore process on the new database.

They conveniently provide a means for you to copy a database between applications with a single command, and without any intermediate storage required:

> As an alternative, you can migrate data between databases that are attached to different applications.
>
> To copy the source database to the target database you will need to invoke pg:copy from the target application, referencing a source database.

Example:

```
heroku pg:copy source-application::OLIVE HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PINK -a target-application
```

Where `source-application` is your existing stack, and `target-application` your newly created one. Not relevant to you, but still worth mentioning, is that any existing data in `target-application`s database will be destroyed.

After this, you might need to promote the database in the new application like so:

```
heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PINK
```

Comment: This is awesome - thanks for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can change your [configuration variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) to point from the new app's database to the existing database. I've done this before without issue (just make sure you have a fresh backup).

So within your new app run `heroku config`. You'll see a reference to your database in `DATABASE_URL`. You can then change the value with:

```
heroku config:set DATABASE_URL=<existing-database-url>
```

At that point you'd have your old app and new app pointing at the same database without issue. As you said, you're paying for the database upgrade on your existing database so deleting your old app shouldn't delete the database; if it does (again you have backups right?) that would be the time to contact Heroku!

If you're not comfortable working with the command line, you can also change the values in your app's **Settings** tab on the Heroku app dashboard.

---

With all of that said, you shouldn't actually need to create a new app in order to upgrade your stack. Again, I've done a stack upgrade before and you ought to be able to do it in place; which [the Heroku docs confirm](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-14-migration#upgrading-the-production-app-to-cedar-14).

Comment: +1 Thank you! The `heroku stack:set` command was the ticket! Somehow I missed it previously - thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Although @Drenmi's approach is probably the safest option it is possible to transfer database "ownership" between apps.
Make sure you make a backup first.

In Heroku databases are treated as Add-Ons. So when you for example push a rails app heroku will add a postgres db addon to the app.

First use `heroku addons` to get a list of the addons attached:

```
$ heroku addons --app old_app

Add-on                                   Plan  Price
───────────────────────────────────────  ────  ─────
heroku-postgresql (resting-fairly-4672)  dev   free 
 └─ as HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CYAN
```

We can then attach the database to the new app.

```
heroku addons:attach resting-fairly-4672 --app new_app
```

And detach it from the old app.

```
heroku addons:detach resting-fairly-4672 -app old_app
```

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/managing-add-ons

Comment: thanks! this really helped me in understanding how databases and other addons work with heroku, and how to manage them via the cli

Comment: @max: Didn't know you could do this. Great find! :-)