# Cheapest solution for external postgresql hosting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am running several websites on Heroku with postgresql databases. Some of them are smaller websites with very few visitors but I still need more than 10.000 rows, which makes it quite costly with its $9/month per website.

For most of them there is really not much load or a lot of data. I don't have high demands on availibility either. Low price, simple usage, 10.000+ rows storage, and external access are my demands.

I have no experience in installing databases and do not wish to maintain a database. I just need to store the data and leave it at that.

Is $9 / month at Heroku the cheapest solution I can find for this? For my php websites mysql-databases are always free so I am quite suprised how pricy it is to store data for Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is discouraged by Heroku, you can share the same instance of your postgres db between many apps. All you have to do, is to get your environment variables from your app and set them into the other ones.

Please check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981508/share-database-between-2-apps-in-heroku).

Comment: Great! I will try this out and see if it works...will get back when I have.