# Heroku Postgres non-permanent credentials

Tags: python, heroku-postgres

I built some hardware based on raspberry pi and wrote some python scripts such that when plugged-in uploads data to the heroku postgres database, previously I uploaded and stored data on a private Github repository. The database is connected to a heroku app that visually displays the data. According to documentation

```
Do not copy and paste database credentials to a separate environment or into your application’s code.
```

I understand that the credentials periodically get rotated, so I cannot use the credentials in my code built into the hardware, but I cannot find a solution for clients upload data outside heroku in a permanent way. I've read this post

[Heroku Permanent Database Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124519/heroku-permanent-database-credentials)

but it just copy and pasted from the documentation. Any suggestions appreciated.