# Connect to existing Heroku Database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli

### **This seems like it should be very simple, however I can't find any solutions.**

I had a server, lets call it "**server1**", and it was connected to a database, lets call it "**database1**". Both the server and database are hosted on **Heroku**.

I have created a new server, lets call it "**server2**", and it is also hosted on **Heroku**.

I want to connect **server2** to **database1**. How do I do this?

Background info:

1. Both servers are using node.js
2. The database is postgreSQL.

---

***server1 -> database1***

***server2 -> null***

How can I make it to where:

***server2 -> database1***

---

I don't care if server1 stays connected or doesn't, I just want to connect server2 to database1.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Share database between 2 apps in Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981508/share-database-between-2-apps-in-heroku)

Answer (score 0):

### Well, I just found the answer, enter this into the server's console:

```
heroku addons:attach <database_name> -a <server_name>
```

Or in my case:

```
heroku addons:attach <database1> -a <server2>
```

Also, server1 will no longer be attached to database1.